# how to use logical operators and tasklist

Tags: windows, batch

I m using logical operators and `tasklist` command in a single sentence but it is not working. My batch script:

```
tasklist \fi"memusage gt 18000" && \fi"memusage lt 19000"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5):

```
::       ↓                          ↓
tasklist /fi "memusage gt 18000"    /fi "memusage lt 19000"
::          ↑                    ↑↑    ↑
```

Explanation (see `tasklist /?` output):

- `↓`  use `/FI` (solidus) instead of <strike>`\FI` (reverse solidus)</strike>;
- `↑`  separate `/FI` switch from filter itself using a space;
- `↑↑` simply concatenated filters mean *logical `AND`* (cf. the last example in `tasklist /?`).

BTW, `&&` operator means [*Conditional Execution*](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on command level only.

Comment: Can you use an OR filter? This works, but it may use more CPU since it runs command twice:
`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad++.exe"`

Comment: @gregg Consecutive applying several filters is the only way of `OR`, AFAIK. I'd switch to PowerShell `Get-Process ` (the `-Name <String[]>` parameter allows very powerful combination of  wildcards in names). You can type multiple process names (separated by commas) and use wildcard characters. Example `Get-Process -Name 'pspad','note*'` returns info for  processes `notepad`, `notepad++` and `PSPad`.